# maven-war-plugin picking up incorrect files

Tags: maven

I have a maven project that runs in the following order:

1) maven-war-plugin: exploded

2 ) maven-antrun-plugin
     - Modifies file in {project.build}/target directory

3)maven-war-plugin:war.

This works and when I look at the modified file in {project.build}/target it has the correct changes.

However the war file that is created contains the file before the changes were made - as if its picking it up from somewhere else? Is this expected? My war plugin is set as follows:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- First step is to disable the default-war build step. -->
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <!-- Second step is to create an exploded war. Done in prepare-package -->
            <id>war-exploded</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <!-- Last step is to make sure that the war is built in the package phase -->
            <id>custom-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Edit 1

See below for ant run plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupid>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupid>
<artificatId>maven-antrun-plugin</artificatId>
<version>1.8</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>prepare-package</phase>
<configuration>
<target>
<unzip src="${baseDir}/target/WEB-INF/xxxx.jar" dest="${baseDir}/tmp" />;
<untar src="{baseDir}/tmp/META-INF/resources/yyyy.tar.gz" dest="{baseDir}/tmp/META-INF/resources/myFolder" compression="gzip" />

<delete file="{baseDir}/tmp/META-INF/resources/yyyy.tar.gz />
<delete file="${baseDir}/target/WEB-INF/xxxx.jar" />

<delete file="{baseDir}/tmp/META-INF/resources/myFolder/info.php" />

<tar compression="gzip" destFile="{baseDir}/tmp/META-INF/resources/yyyy.tar.gz">
<tarfileset
dir={baseDir}/tmp/META-INF/resources/">
<include name="myFolder/** />
</tarfileset>
</tar>

<jar destfile="${baseDir}/target/WEB-INF/xxxx.jar" basedir="${baseDir}/tmp/"/>

<delete dir="${baseDir}/tmp/" />
</target>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>run</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Edit 2.

After the maven-war-plugin:exploded has ran and the ant task runs the artifact is modified in the target directory as expected.

When the maven-war-plugin-war package runs it picks up the un modified file.

Comment: Can you show us configuration of antrun plugin?

Comment: Added some edits to the bottom of the post